# How can I tell if a Mac App Store app is a universal purchase?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, mac-appstore

> Apple has announced that it is officially launching the ability for developers to sell Mac and iOS apps as a single purchase.
>
> The macOS version of your app can now be included in a universal purchase, allowing customers to enjoy your app and in‑app purchases across iOS, iPadOS, macOS, watchOS, and tvOS by purchasing only once.
>
> ([source](https://9to5mac.com/2020/03/23/apple-officially-rolls-out-universal-purchase-support-for-mac-and-ios-apps/))

For example, GoodNotes 5 [is a universal app](https://support.goodnotes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001438536-Installing-GoodNotes-for-macOS-for-free-when-you-already-bought-it-on-your-iPhone-or-iPad), but I know it only through the linked support article. [Its Mac App Store page](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/goodnotes-5/id1444383602) only says the iPhone and iPad counterpart apps are available, but nothing about those being universal (or not).

The other app I'm looking at is [iA Writer for Mac OS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ia-writer/id775737590) (but could be any other app, really), and unlike the Good Notes 5, I couldn't find any external mention of iA Writer being bundled with the iOS and ipadOS apps as a single purchase.

So can I somehow tell myself, without contacting the developers every time I need an answer, just by looking at the App Store pages, it's source code, or maybe making and API call of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer: you will have to find the app on both Mac and iOS App Stores, get the shareable link and compare the IDs. If those match, chances are it's a bundled app.

**UPD**: The next day after posting this, iA Writer Support sent me a reply which doesn't conflict with my above theory:

> > If I buy the app on the Mac App Store, is it a universal purchase and are the iOS counterparts for iPhone and iPad bundled with it? Or will I have to purchase them separately?
>
> The software licenses for iA Writer are platform specific requiring a separate purchase for each. All of our apps are developed independently and unlike subscription services or login based apps, you own iA Writer on whichever platform you've purchased it for.
>
> Use of iA Writer on iOS would require purchasing iA Writer for iOS available here: [iA Writer for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id775737172?mt=12)